# Le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif

> La vue de la petite madeleine ne m'avait rien rappelé avant que je n'y eusse goûté.
>
> (Proust, *À la recherche du temps perdu*)

Je sais bien que le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif se limite à la langue soutenue, mais je voudrais quand même comprendre sa valeur dans cette phrase particulière. Il est dit dans mon livre de grammaire française que ce temps indique que l'action de la proposition subordonnée précède celle de la proposition principale. Néanmoins, dans ce cas, la proposition subordonnée est introduite par « avant que ». Pourquoi le plus-que-parfait est-il employé ici ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu n'as pas lu le bon manuel de grammaire française ;-)

Voici ce que dit le mien (c'est moi qui souligne):

> [...] Les conjonctions composées de *que*, qui régissent l'Indicatif, sont celles-cy. 1. Celles qui signifient la quantité, comme ; *Je vous aime plus que vous ne m'aimez, autant que vous m'aimez, moins que vous ne m'aimez*. 2 Celles qui signifient le tems, comme ; *Pendant que vous êtes icy, dez que, ou, depuis que j'ay sceu vôtre maladie. Aussi-tôt que, incontinent que, soudain que, après que vous serez arrivé, que vous fustes arrivé, que vous êtes venu ici. Lors que vous arriviez, que vous arrivâtes, que vous êtes arrivé, que vous arriverez. Tant que, cy-longtems que vous êtes icy, que vous serez icy.* **Excepté** : ***Avant que vous soyez-la**, **que vous vinssiez icy*** ; *Devant que vous fussiez au monde*; *Jusqu'à ce que vous soyez entierement guéri[...]*
>
> *Essay d'une parfaite grammaire de la langue françoise*, [Laurent Chifflet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Chifflet), 1659

On trouve quantité d'imparfaits du subjonctif à la suite d'*avant que*, par exemple :

> *Je savais le Capitole et son plant, **avant que je ne susse le Louvre** : et le Tibre avant la Seine*
>
> *Essais, livre 3, chapitre 9*, Montaigne, 1595.

> *Je n'ai et je n'espère aucun bien, ô divin Jésus ! dont je ne sois redevable à ces larmes, à ces prières, à cette pénitence, à ce jeûne, à cet amour que vous aviez pour moi, **avant que je ne fusse, avant que je vous connusses, avant que je vous aimasse, et que je pusse vous prier.***
>
> *Les souffrances de nôtre Seigneur Jésus-Christ*, Thomé de Jésus, 1740

> *[...] il était assez bien, à une petite toux près, jusqu'au moment où il fut attaqué, quatre jours **avant que je ne le visse**.*
>
> *Journal de médecine, chirurgie et pharmacie*, A Roux, 1766, p 206

Answer (score 0):

La réponse est toute logique donc simple :

La concordance des temps grammaticaux = Si la proposition principale se trouve être dans le passé, la proposition subordonnée ( introduite p.ex. par une locution conjonctive *avant que*) doit impérativement suivre le même régime de temps grammatical mais à la forme antérieure comme les actions des deux propositions n'ont pas eu lieu en même temps : Une action a eu lieu avant l'autre.

Deuxième point: *Avant que* requiert l'emploi du subjonctif, donc, en l'occurrence celui du subjonctif du plus-que-parfait de la proposition subordonnée dont l'action aura/aurait, si jamais, lieu plus tard. Les deux propositions grammaticales doivent être dans la même logique du passé, selon la concordance des temps.